# copying files from one folder to another on mounted partition using php and linux

Tags: php, linux, cp

I installed `apache2` server on my host. I want to copy the folder or files from on mounted drive to another mounted drive. I am using

```
system('sudo cp -rf /source/* /destination/')
```

in `PHP` to do this task. The problem is it doesn't executing from `PHP` but same command to the copying task from command line. There might be permission issue, but I am unable to figure out the reason. Have anybody done this, if yes please guide me.

Comment: Which user are you using while you do the `cp` test in commandline?

Comment: Add 2>&1 to the end of your command to redirect errors from stderr to stdout. This should make it clear what's going wrong.

Comment: this is what output i am getting after adding 2>&1       "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified Sorry, try again. sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified Sorry, try again. sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified Sorry, try again. sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts"

Comment: Its working now. I just changed the directory permission to the user of same as apache server is which is www-data and did not use sudo for cp command. But what if i want to access root directory?